# Is there a way to make "Apple Push Services" certificate life time valid?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the "Apple Push Services" certificate for apps notifications, but as I can see, the certificate can be valid to about 1 year, and then it have to be renewed.

Is there anyway to make these certificates without expiration date?

Comment: No, you need to renew the certificate in case it has been leaked and to ensure that your developer membership is still in good standing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You need to renew your certificate every year because it can ensure your developers account is still active and in working state.